# How to allow multiple onTouch events to exist on a canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have the following app which allows a circle to be drawn on touch.  When the screen is touched a second time the first touch circle is removed and a new circle is created where the second touch occurs.  How can allow multiple circles to appear for as many times the screen is touched?(i.e. 5 touch events = 5 circles appear on the same canvas in their touch locations).

```
public class Lab12Activity extends Activity {
Point pt = new Point();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new DrawView(this));
}

class DrawView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawCircle(pt.x, pt.y, 15, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 225, 150, paint);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(30);
        canvas.drawText("Clear", 75, 75, paint);
        canvas .drawText("Tap to add Circles", 300, 75, paint);


    }
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {


        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            pt.x = (int) event.getX();
            pt.y = (int) event.getY();

            invalidate();


        }
        return true;

    }
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [event.getActionIndex ();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getActionIndex%28%29) it returns the pointer index of the touch event.